# Distribution of midpoints in a unit disk

Tags: probability, integration, geometry

I'm trying to find a probability distribution $m(r,\theta)$ defined over a unit disk which represents the probability of a point being the midpoint of two randomly chosen points in said disk. I think that I'm pretty close to the answer, but I'm off by a factor of 16 and I don't understand why. Given that the distribution of points is uniform, i.e. $f(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi}$, my reasoning is as follows:

1. The first and second points chosen are $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ respectively. If we fix the first point chosen inside the disk, the set of points which are possible midpoints for $P_{1}P_{2}$ form a disk of radius $\frac{1}{2}$. (Edit: see the figure below for an illustration)
2. Since for each possible $P_{1}$ there is a unique circle of size $\frac{\pi}{4}$ generated representing *all* the possible midpoints where $P_{1}$ is one of the points, then $m(r,\theta)$ should be proportional to the total "height" of all the unique circles that overlap onto the point $(r,\theta)$, if we imagine each of the radius-$\frac{1}{2}$ circles as having some infinitesimal "height".
3. I found the "height" of the overlapping circles to be $2(\frac{\arccos{r}}{4}-\frac{r}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{r^{2}}{4}}) = \frac{1}{2}(\arccos{r}-r\sqrt{1-r^{2}})$. This is the area of overlap between two circles of size $\frac{\pi}{4}$, reason being that since the center of the radius-$\frac{1}{2}$ disks we formed in step 2 will fall within a radius-$\frac{1}{2}$ disk that is concentric to the unit disk, then the set of radius-$\frac{1}{2}$ disks which **do not** overlap onto $(r,\theta)$ must be more than a distance of $\frac{1}{2}$ from this point. Hence, the set of radius-$\frac{1}{2}$ disks which **do** form the "height" at point $(r,\theta)$ will have centers within a distance of $\frac{1}{2}$ from the point, and this is the leaf-shaped area between two circles - essentially the expression above. I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to be thinking about the "height" at the point - or if "height" is even the right way to think about it - so I would appreciate if anyone can point out a more rigorous direction.
4. Assuming step 3 is correct, then because $f(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi}$, then since we are choosing 2 points, we scale step 3 by $\frac{1}{\pi^{2}}$. However, if we take this as $m(r,\theta)$, then $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}m(r,\theta)r d\theta dr = \frac{1}{16}$.

I'm not very well versed in geomtery and probability, so there is definitely something wrong with my logic. Can anyone point me to where the missing factor of 16 comes from, or whether my entire chain of logic is incorrect?

Figure for step 1:
We just need to show that the boundary of the set of possible midpoints forms a circle.

[image]

Consider the diameter that goes through $P_{1}$ and the center of the circle. If $P_{2}$ is on either $D_{1}$ or $D_{2}$, then the midpoint will be at $M_{1}$ or $M_{2}$ respectively. Consider if $P_{2}$ is anywhere else on the larger circle, let's say $A$ (any point on the circle will form the boundary case), then its midpoint we call $X$. $M_{1}P_{1} = \frac{1}{2}D_{1}P_{1}, XP_{1} = \frac{1}{2}AP_{1}$ and $\angle{M_{1}P_{1}X} = \angle{D_{1}P_{1}A}$, so $M_{1}P_{1}X$ and $D_{1}P_{1}A$ are similar triangles by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. A similar argument can be applied for $D_{2}$ and $M_{2}$. Hence we have that $D_{1}D_{2}A$ is similar to $M_{1}M_{2}X$ by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. Since $D_{1}D_{2}A$ is a right triangle, so is $M_{1}M_{2}X$, and as A varies, X will trace out a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$.

P.S. I am quite sure that other than the factor of 16, everything else *should* be correct, because this is part of a larger problem that I am solving, which I have shown to be correct assuming that the factor of 16 is there.

Comment: I don't understand what your "height" is. Anyway, if the midpoint $M$ of $P_1P_2$ is at a distance $r$ from the center $O$ of the disk, then $P_1$ and $P_2$ must lie in the circular segment delimited by the chord through $M$ perpendicular to $MO$, or in its reflection about the chord. This region has an area $4\arccos r-2r\sqrt{1-r^2}$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks for the suggestion, I edited to make "height" a bit more clear. Still not sure whether it's a legitimate way to be thinking about the probability distribution. Anyways, I agree with your point about where $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ lie, just that I don't see how it helps to find $m(r,\theta)$. Also I believe that this area should be $2(\arccos{r} - r\sqrt{1-r^{2}})$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Now that I think of it, I think I see where you're going - this was one of my previous lines of thought which I left off after a while. But if we integrate in a similar way to what was done in step 4, we still have a missing factor of 4.

Comment: It's much clearer now. Besides, I just included your drawing into the text of your question.

Comment: You are right about the area: I mistyped it. And now I understand your reasoning. Anyway, as you say "$(,)$ should be **proportional** to the total height", it shouldn't be a surprise if the final result must be normalised.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, that's much better.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Right, but I'm trying to find the reason why the normalization just happens to be 16x, or 4x by your method, because surely there is a reason why the distribution needs to be scaled by this much to become a proper probability distribution.

Comment: Forget about the middle point, since if $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed in the the unit disc, you are asking for the distribution of $(X+Y)/2$ while it is easier to deal with $X+Y.$ Now this two dimension distribution is invariant by rotation, therefore its knowledge is given by the distribution of its square norm $|X|^2+|Y|^2+2\langle X,Y\rangle$ which is the same as $U+V+2\sqrt{UV}Z$ where $ U,V,Z$ are independent with $U$ and $V$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and $Z$ has the arcsin distribution on $(-1,1)$ with density proportional to $(1-z^2)^{-1/2}.$

Comment: @GérardLetac Sorry, I am not knowledgeable enough about probability to understand what you meant. Could you perhaps point me to some resources or explain in more detail? For example, why does the squared norm of $X+Y$ have to do with this? Also, where did $Z$ come from and why is it an arcsin distribution? Thanks.

Comment: @GérardLetac Very very interesting comment. Can you give some reference(s) ?

Comment: @wjch: if a distribution in $R^2$ is invariant by rotation it is useless to look for its density in $R^2$ : it is more informative to look for the density of its distance $R$ to $0$. Here saying something of $R^2$ is easier than for $R$. With the above notation, since the density of |X| is $2r$, then the density of $U=|X|^2$ is 1. The scalar product of $X$ and $Y$ is $|X||Y|\cos \Theta$ where  $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$ and therefore $Z=\cos \Theta\sim \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}.$ I am not sure that my remark is useful, but it gives moments.  Answers :  obscure !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area of the wedge subtended by the green arc is $R^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)$ and the area of the red triangle is $r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$. Therefore, the area of the gray lozenge is $2\!\left(R^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)-r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right)$. The gray lozenge is the locus of endpoints of lines, contained in the left disk, with $P$ as a midpoint. The area of the lozenge is proportional to the probability density of the midpoints of lines whose endpoints are uniformly distributed in the left disk.

[image]

We compute the normalization factor for the density with
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^R2\left(R^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)-r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right) 2\pi r\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=4\pi R^4\int_0^1\left(\cos^{-1}(r)-r\sqrt{1-r^2}\right)r\,\mathrm{d}r\tag{1a}\\
&=4\pi R^4\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac12\cos^2(r)\,\mathrm{d}r-\frac12\int_0^1r^{1/2}(1-r)^{1/2}\,\mathrm{d}r\right)\tag{1b}\\
&=4\pi R^4\left(\frac\pi8-\frac12\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac32\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac32\right)}{\Gamma(3)}\right)\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2R^4}4\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ substitute $r\mapsto Rr$
$\text{(1b):}$ split the integral
$\phantom{\text{(1b):}}$ substitute $r\mapsto\cos(r)$ and integrate by parts in the left integral
$\phantom{\text{(1b):}}$ substitute $r\mapsto r^{1/2}$ in the right integral
$\text{(1c):}$ integrate using the [Beta Function Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$\text{(1d):}$ simplify

Here is another way to get $\text{(1d)}$. For any point $p$ in the disk, the midpoint, $m$, to the other endpoint varies over a disk of radius $\frac R2$. Thus, for each $p$, we integrate over the area covered by $m$, and then we integrate over all $p$ in the disk; that is, $\pi\frac{R^2}{4}\cdot\pi R^2=\frac{\pi^2R^4}4$.

So the density would be
$$
\frac8{\pi^2R^4}\left(R^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)-r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right)\tag2
$$
which, for $R=1$, is
$$
\frac8{\pi^2}\left(\cos^{-1}(r)-r\sqrt{1-r^2}\right)\tag3
$$

Comment: This is along the same lines as what you have in the question, and includes the normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why is there a normalization factor and is the point of calculating just to normalize the distribution? If so, is there some intuitive reason why there is a normalization factor at all, instead of the distribution being already normalized?

Comment: In general, we often integrate a density over a given region and to compute the probability of being in a certain subregion, we divide the integral over the subregion by the integral over the given region. In this case, the density of the endpoints is uniform with respect to area, so we compute the area of the possible endpoints given a midpoint. This gives a density at that given midpoint, but to compute a *probability density*, we need to divide by the integral of this density over the whole disk so that the integral of the density is $1$.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But then since the distribution of endpoints is a probability distribution, wouldn't the distribution of midpoints as calculated by this method still be a probability distribution? I just still can't see where this seemingly arbitrary constant comes from, other than being the integral over the unnormalized density.

Comment: I have added a confirmation of $\text{(1d)}$.

Comment: Writing (3) as $f(r)$ I get $$\int_0^1 f(r)\,dr = \frac{32}{3\pi^2},\qquad \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 f(r)r\,dr\,d\phi=2.$$ So it's not clear to me how (3) is normalized, either as an integral over $r\in[0,1]$ or as an integral over the unit disk. (From numerical methods, I think the correct prefactor in (3) is $16r/\pi$.)

Comment: Mathematica gives `1` for `Integrate[8/Pi^2(ArcCos[r]-r Sqrt[1-r^2])r,{r,0,1},{t,0,2Pi}]`